# Recursive self join and transposition

Tags: python, recursion, transpose, self-join

I have a data set that tracks parent/child relationships across multiple measurement cycles. This looks like

```
[["Col1","Col2"],
 ["A","B"],
 ["B","C"],
 ["C","D"]]
```

I would like this to appear as

```
[["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"],
 ["A","B","C","D"]]
```

I have seen other examples in SQL, but none of those seem to answer my question. I'm looking for a full columnar expansion of the data.

I have investigated self-joins and transposition, but neither of those quite get me there.

This should not require hyper-specialized python packages since I need to port this over to a few other coding languages.

Update: second example:
If I had a data set such as

```
[["Col1","Col2"],
 ["A","B1"],
 ["B1","C1"],
 ["B1,"C2"],
 ["C2,"D"],
 ["A,"B2"]]
```

I would expect:

```
[["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"],
 ["A","B1","C1",""],
 ["A","B1","C2","D"],
 ["A","B2","",""]]
```

Comment: i like that you kept it generic, but your example might end up being too oversimplified and producing answers that may not exactly apply. Do you expect your data to be provided as column names in first index and just values in second? Do the values tend to be joined at the "tail" so to speak? This might be too vague as is.

Comment: `col3` and `col4` ? where did they come from?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh - good points. The index and column names are not important so much as the order of the columns.

Joining at the tail AND head should occur since the first item in the first column may not be the true head, but actually a 'local head'. Instead I would need to move in both forward and reverse from some arbitrary value.

Comment: Please use words to explain exactly what you are doing. Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

gives you the result you want:

```
fam = [["Col1","Col2"],["A","B"],["B","C"],["C","D"]]

col, chi, res = [], [], []

for i in fam:
    for ii in i:
        if len(ii) == 1:
            if ii in chi:
                chi.remove(ii)
            chi.append(ii)
        else:
            col.append(ii)

res.append(col)
res.append(chi)

>>>print(res)
>>>[['Col1', 'Col2'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dict of lists from the parent-child pairs that maps each parent to a list of children, find the top parents by using set difference between the dict keys and the set of children, make these top parents the children of `None`, so that you can recursively build the joined lists from the mapping dict starting with `None` as the top-most parent, but ignore `None` when outputting the joined lists:

```
def join(pairs):
    def _join(parent=None):
        if parent not in tree:
            return [[parent]]
        output = []
        for child in tree[parent]:
            for joined in _join(child):
                output.append([*([parent] if parent else []), *joined])
        return output
    tree = {}
    children = set()
    for parent, child in pairs:
        tree.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
        children.add(child)
    for parent in tree.keys() - children:
        tree.setdefault(None, []).append(parent)
    return _join()
```

so that given:

```
pairs = [
    ["A", "B1"],
    ["B1", "C1"],
    ["B1", "C2"],
    ["C2", "D"],
    ["A", "B2"]
]
```

`joined(pairs)` would return:

```
[['A', 'B1', 'C1'], ['A', 'B1', 'C2', 'D'], ['A', 'B2']]
```

Now if you want to fill the rows with less columns with empty strings, you can get the maximum number of columns first, and then iterate through the rows to extend them with enough empty strings to make them of equal number of columns:

```
joined = join(pairs)
max_columns = max(map(len, joined))
for path in joined:
    path.extend([''] * (max_columns - len(path)))
```

`joined` would become:

```
[['A', 'B1', 'C1', ''], ['A', 'B1', 'C2', 'D'], ['A', 'B2', '', '']]
```

Note that I'm ignoring the column headers such as `['Col1', 'Col2']` in your question because they are not relevant to the problem, and you did not provide an explanation as to where `'Col3'` and `'Col4'` come from.